# Faster way to count files in Python

Tags: python

I want to know how many files are in a folder (specifically a shared network folder on windows if that makes a difference here).

I am using this code right now:

```
include os.path
def countFiles(path):
    return len([f for f in os.listdir(path)
                if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(path, f))])
```

It works fine when there are a few files in the folder, but it takes a noticably long time in a directory with many files (say 4000). I am running this frequently (files are being added every ~15 seconds) so the slowdown is painful.

In my particular case, I know there aren't any subfolders, so I could skip the `os.path.isfile` check, but I'd like to keep my solution general.  Frankly, I am surprised that there isn't a built in # of files function on os.path.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order to know how many files there are in a folder, the system *must* enumerate each entry, then it *must* check whether an entry is a file or not. There's no faster way unless the system provides you with a filesystem event (e.g. `fsevent` or `eventfd`) to tell you when things change.

These operations are slow for a disk-based filesystem (tens to hundreds of microseconds), and even slower on a network drive; you'll notice they are pretty slow even in a normal file browser. Modern OSes deal with the slowness through aggressive caching, but this has its limits (especially for network filesystems, where the overhead of keeping the cache fresh can exceed the cost of doing the operations in the first place).

To speed it up, you could cache the `isfile` result for names you've already checked, under the assumption that they won't transmute into directories. This would save you many `isfile` checks, at the expense of a bit of safety (if e.g. someone deletes a file and replaces it with an identically-named folder).

Comment: +1 there's no way you're going to do this without upsetting a sysadmin

Comment: This makes sense.  Maybe there is a windows hook I can use to get the number of files in a folder?  If I leave the directory open in explorer, it constantly tells me the number of files and updates rapidly (since everything is cached). If it has a more efficient way to track this, it might be better to let the OS handle it.